# I want to use multiple select command in sql

Tags: sql, select

I am Beginner in sql. I want following result using connecting two tables.

Here are details.

Table1(usertb)

```
id username  password fname   lname
---------------------------------
1  amit      abc111   amit    ganatra
2  rakesh    r111     rakesh  patel
3  sanajay   s111     sanjay  Mor
```

Table2 (friendlist)

```
id   fid
--------
1     2
1     3
```

It means id no 1 has two friends whose idno is 1 and 2. When user of id=1 logged in there should be friendlist like,

```
2  rakesh patel
3  sanjay Mor
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [show combined data of various tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144335/show-combined-data-of-various-tables) - there is no need to duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a join.

```
Select t1.fname, t1.lname From table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.fid = t1.id
Where t2.id = 1
```

A couple of sql courses would stand you in good stead, stop what you are doing and take one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select table2.fid, tabel1.fname + table1.lname 
from table1 innerjoin table2 on table2.fid = table1.id
```

Comment: Thanks Angelo...It helped me a lot...Once Again thanks