# show combined data of various tables

Tags: sql, select, join

can anybody help me to solve how to write a query regarding my task...

Task is

I have created two table which are described following..

**Table1= Usertb**

```
id   name   age  city
1    Hiren   30  UK
2    Sakir   29  Russia
3    Anil    32  Japan
4    Ankur   29  Kenya
```

**Table2= Friendtb**

```
id   fid
1    3
1    4
2    1
```

Now, I want to display like this..suppose user of id=1 is logged in...

```
1 Hiren 30 Uk   3 Anil 32 Japan    
1 Hiren 30 Uk   4 Ankur 29 Kenya.
```

(In short i want to display both data)..

thanks

Comment: Read a liitle about JOIN statements. You need only a simple JOIN in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060325/mysql-query-join-inner-join

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT T1.id,T1.name,T1.age,T1.city,T2.Name,T2.Age
FROM Usertb T1 JOIN Friendtb F1 ON T1.id = F1.id
JOIN Usertb T2 ON T2.id= T1.fiD
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will produce the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT Usertb1.id, Usertb1.name, Usertb1.age, Usertb1.city, Usertb2.id, Usertb2.name, Usertb2.age, Usertb2.city
  FROM Usertb Usertb1 
    INNER JOIN Friendtb ON Usertb1.id = Friendtb.id
    INNER JOIN Usertb Usertb2 ON Usertb2.id = Friendtb.fid
```